# I'm creating a bot for steam trading, having some trouble adding up array values

Tags: node.js, steam

At the moment I am trying to create a steam trading bot that only accepts offers if the items being received are worth more than the items being given.......

```
var market = require('steam-market-pricing');

var names = [
    'AWP | Safari Mesh (Factory New)',
    'AWP | Safari Mesh (Minimal Wear)',
    'AWP | Safari Mesh (Field-Tested)',
    'AWP | Safari Mesh (Well-Worn)',
    'AWP | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)'
];




market.getItemsPrice(730, names, function(data) {
    for(var i in names) {
        console.log(names[i] + data[names[i]]['median_price']);
    }
});
```

The code above can find the individual prices of the items that I listed in the "names" array, but how would I add up each of their prices to create a total?

[Here's the package I used to find prices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-market-pricing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning

```
var temp = data[names[i]]['median_price'].substring(1);
```

---

**Reason why your code was not working?**

Since the string contained the currency sign before the price, you got the result "NaN" while trying to execute this code.

```
parseFloat(data[names[i]]['median_price'])
```

**Solution**

`var temp = data[names[i]]['median_price'].substring(1)`;

This would remove the currency sign from the start of the string.

I have modified Snuckus's code to include the code. I have mentioned at the beginning. This will definitely give the totals.

```
market.getItemsPrice(730, names, function(data) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i in names) {
        var temp = data[names[i]]['median_price'].substring(1);
        total += parseFloat(temp);
        console.log(total);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var total = 0;
for(var i in names) {
    total += parseFloat(data[names[i]]['median_price']);
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Tried doing this, and got "NaN" as a return.